# Stacking numpy array A corresponding to array B

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array (ndarray, each of shape `(1, 10, 4)`) of input features `X`, and a label array `y` corresponding to classes.

Now I want to create a new array of arrays by stacking together, all input features in `X` that correspond to `class 0` in `y`, features that correspond to `class 1` in `y`, etc... so that a new array of arrays is formed, with nested the arrays equal to the number classes.

As a minimal example, say I have:

```
X = np.random.randn(200, 1, 10, 4)
a = np.zeros(100, dtype=int)
b = np.ones(100, dtype=int)
y = np.hstack((a,b))
```

So,

```
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
(200, 1, 10, 4)
(200,)
```

New array then should then be like:

```
Final = [array(#all_features_of class_0), array(#all_features_of_class_1)...]
```

My intention is to plot these features per class to understand their distribution.

If it may help, every single observation has `4` features, so the **4** in `(1, 10, 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did I understood you correct, is this what you want?

```
class0, class1=[],[]
for i in range(len(y)):
if y[i]==0:
    class0.append(X[i])
else:
    class1.append(X[i])
Final = (np.array(class0) , np.array(class1))
```

Comment: yes, but then `len(class0)` gives `100` and `len(class1)` gives `1` , and in the MWE, all classes have 100 elements..

Comment: Both classes are of len 100, as I see in my output, and it just depends upon number of 0 and 1 array y.